# Enviar ID de cada passada respectiva do while

Tags: php

O código que possuo é um carrinho de compras, certo que exibe as compras separadas em vendedores, podendo ter mais de um vendedor no carrinho de compras como na imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora oq eu preciso é passar para a etapa seguinte do processo de compra, em outra pagina e com os item somente do vendedor que escolhi, por isso vou usar o ID do vendedor que consigo na pagina que cria o carrinho, e então ligo a um botão "comprar" que envia pra mim. Ate ai ok. 
o problema é que ele sempre envia o ultimo id carregado, e não o respectivo id do qual eu cliquei... como posso resolver isso? segue o código:
esse é do form q envia a variável ID da loja e ele muda a cada passada do while.

```
echo '<center><button class="btn btn-success" rel="5" onclick="submete();">Comprar</button></center>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</table>';                          
                        echo '<form id="envia" method="POST" action="envia.php">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="total" value="'.$codigo_loja.'" />';          
                        echo'</form>';
```

Comment: por que ao inves de enviar um post com o id nao manda pra proxima pagina com o ID na url tipo `nome-da-proxima-pagina.php?id_vendedor=xxx` ??

Comment: pois é o id da loja, desejo deixar oculto. mas essa é uma boa estratégia.

Comment: minha opniao que se ele nao pode ser exibido voce precisa encontrar outra solucao, esta deixando complicado por nada. Se abrir o console do navegador da pra encontrar, o id da loja do mesmo jeito, ate olhando o codigo fonte consegue, o fato de enviar como post nao vai dexa-lo invisivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você trabalha com vários formulários, coloque o botão submit dentro do formulário e insira o type submit nele. Assim:

```
echo '<form id="envia" method="POST" action="envia.php">'; // <-- aqui

echo '<center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="5" onclick="submete();">Comprar</button></center>';
//                            ^ 
//                            .............. aqui
echo '</td>';
echo '</table>';                          

echo '<input type="hidden" name="total" value="'.$codigo_loja.'" />';          
echo'</form>';
```

Provavelmente isso irá resolver o problema.

Comment: NOSSA GOD DEMAIS, VALEU SEU LINDO!

Comment: @douglasdutra kkkkk tranquilo